Ramification at particular level of a tower of extensions of local field
Let $K$ be an unramified extension of the $p$-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Suppose we have a tower of extensions:
$$K=:K(u_0) \subset K(u_1) \subset K(u_2) \subset K(u_3) \subset \cdots \subset K(u_n) \subset \cdots $$
such that $u_n$ is algebraic over $K(u_{n-1})$. More precisely, assume that $u_n$ is a zero of the polynomial $$f(x)={\color{blue}{x^{p^5}+\cdots (\text{terms involving}~ x)+p^{p^2+1}x}}+u_{n-1} \in K(u_{n-1})[x], ~n \geq 2$$ of degree $p^5$. The blue colour part remains unchanged. Alternatively (as @Will Sawin remarked), there is a polynomial $f(x,y)$ of degree $p^5$ in $y$ such that $f(u_{n-1}, u_n)=0$.

$u_1=p^{\frac{1}{p^5}}$ is known, but I don't know about other $u_n, ~ n \geq 2 $. We know about the $p$-adic valuation of $u_n$ is given by $v_p(u_n)=\frac{1}{p^{5n}}$. (I am ignoring the numerator of the valuation, just simply put 1)

Suppose that we know $K(u_n)/ K(u_{n-1})$ is totally ramified for all $n \neq 2$ and also we know that the first level of extension $K(u_1)/K$ is totally ramified.


So we have total ramification at the first level, and the third level onwards, but we don't know any information on ramification for the extension $K(u_2)/ K(u_1)$.
Can we say about the ramification of the extension $K(u_2)/K(u_1)$?

Since the successive extensions after 3rd level are totally ramified, $K(u_n)/K(u_2)$ is also totally ramified.
Also given that $K(u_1)/K$ is totally ramified.
According to the definition of $f(x)$; $u_2$, $u_3, \cdots$ are, respectively, roots of
\begin{align}
f(x)&={\color{blue}{x^{p^5}+\cdots (\text{terms involving}~ x)+p^{p^2+1}x}}+u_{1} \in K(u_1)[x] \\
f(x)&={\color{blue}{x^{p^5}+\cdots (\text{terms involving}~ x)+p^{p^2+1}x}}+u_{2} \in K(u_2)[x] \\
\cdots
\end{align}
Note that the blue part doesn't change, only the constant term changes.
If we had $K(u_n)/K$ totally ramified, it would force $K(u_2)/K(u_1)$ to be totally ramified.
Since the algebraic elements $u_n$ are satisfying the same polynomial except, and since $K(u_n)/ K(u_{n-1})$ is totally ramified for $n \geq 3$, I guess for the same reason $K(u_2)/K(u_1)$ can be totally ramified, as the elements $u_n$ are dependent by a relation.
I am looking for an affirmative situation.
I appreciate your help. Thanks

If the tower is infinitely large, then $u_0$ is arbitrarily $p$-divisible as an element of the splitting field of $f$ over $K$ and hence is a root of unity, so all the $u_i$ are roots of unity. Is this what you intend?

@WillSawin, yes the tower is infinitely large, however, $u_i$ are roots of $p$ instead of unity. Let me edit my question, I forgot it

Your hypothesis are now certainly contradictory. If the $u_i$ are roots of $p$ then their $p$-adic valuations are positive but less then or equal to $1$. Since $u_n = \sqrt[p^5]{p^{n-1}}$, the $p$-adic valuation is equal to the $p$-adic valuation of $u_{n-1}$ divided by $p^5$.
So the $p$-adic valuation of $u_n$ is positive but less than or equal to $p^{-5n}$.
It follows that the minimal polynomial of $u_n$ over any unramified extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q_p$ has degree at least $p^{5n}$, since the $p$-adic valuation must be a slope of the Newton polygon of this polynomial which also must have integer vertices, contradicting for $n>1$ that $u_n$ is the root of a polynomial $f$ of degree $p^5$.

Though my extra assumption was contradictory but my orginal purpose was to know an answer if we can speak about total ramification at a particular level of a tower, provided we know ramification information about previous and later level of that particular level. Can we refine the above $u_n$? For example, let $u_1=p^{\frac{m}{p^5}},~\gcd(p^5, m)=1$ and $u_n=\sqrt[p^5]{u_{n-1}}$. In that case, $p$-adic valuation of $u_n$ is greater than $p^{-5n}$. Does it still contradict?

And what about the case when $u_n$ are roots of unity, in your first comment? Does my question have an answer in that case?

@Learner  In the roots of unity case the argument in fact shows these are prime-to-$p$ roots of unity which means the extensions are all the same, so they are trivially all totally ramified over each other. In the $p$-power case it still contradicts, it's actually the denominator rather than the size of the valuation that matters.

@Learner I think you would find my answers more helpful if you thought carefully to formulate a single question that encapsulates a specific situation you want to know more about.

Maybe I should clarify that when I am saying $u_n$ is a zero of a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $p^5$, I am considering over the ground field $K(u_{n-1})$. Of course, over the ground field $K$, successive degrees will be multiplied.

So can we, now, say something about the ramification of $K(u_2)/k(u_1)$ in the above situation, provided $K(u_1)/K$ and $K(u_n)/K(u_2)$ are totally ramified?

@Learner Do you mean there exists a polynomial in two variables $f(x,y)$ of degree $p^5$ in $y$ such that $f(u_{n-1}, u_n)=0$ for all $n \geq 2$? Can you edit your question based on your new understanding? It's confusing to have multiple contradictory versions. For example you presumably don't mean $u_n = \sqrt[p^5]{u_{n-1}}$ unless $f$ has the very special form. I suspect the final version of the question will be very hard, though.

Yes, I mean such a polynomial you mentioned. However,  I think we can treat $u_{n-1}$ as constant, as the polynomial of $u_n$ is being considered over the ground field  $K(u_{n-1})$. Please check my edited question.

@Learner The facts that $K$ is an unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, $u_1 = p^{1/p^5}$, and the $p$-adic valuation of $u_2$ is $1/p^{10}$ already imply that $\mathbb Q_p(u_2)/\mathbb Q_p(u_1)$ is totally ramified. An extension of a $p$-adic field of degree $n$ is totally ramified if and only if it contains an element of valuation $1/n$ times the valuation of the uniformizer of the base field. In this case $n=p^5$ and the valuation of the uniformizer is $1/p^5$.

great. I just want to understand the third paragraph of your answer above. You said the minimal polynomial of $u_n$ must have degree $p^{5n}$ over any unramified extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.  Why is so? How does $K$ being unramified imply this? Can you please explain it or add a reference?

and also explain, how is the fact $K$ unramified required in your last comment?

@Learner An extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ is unramified if and only if the valuation of the uniformizer of the extension is $1$. Indeed one can define the ramification index of an extension $K/F$ as the ratio of the valuations of the uniformizers of $K$ and $F$, and the extension is unramified if and only if the ramification index is $1$.  The degree is always a multiple of the ramification index, and this justifies the third paragraph of the answer.

@Learner For the comment, the point is that $u_1$ has valuation $1/p^5$ so $K(u_1)$ clearly contains elements of valuation $1/p^5$ but as an extension of $K$ its degree is $p^5$ so by the ramification index fact it can only contain elements of valuation integer multiples of $p^5$.
